# Formula to calculate net winnings

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am making income/outcome worksheet like shown on the screenshot.

[image: Income/Outcome Excel worksheet]

What I want to do is to have a cell (net sum), for example, F2 which automatically updates from the information I provide in column B, C and D.

The formula should look something like this `IF(D:D="Lose",-B:B,+C:C)`.

How can I do this?

Comment: You already show a formula that does things. So do that thing to fit your requirement in that cell?

Comment: Wrap it in SUM() and confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you suggest in your formula is a little different than how I would calculate net winnings. What you suggest will give you a net win of -1. But as your sheet shows, you want a net win of -3.

Instead of your approach, try this:

```
=SUMIF(D2:D8,"Win",C2:C8)-SUM(B2:B8)
```

This calculates the total pots won and subtracts all buy-ins, not just those on pots you lost. For your sample data, this returns -3.

Comment: good point ! even when you win, there is still a cost of the initial buy in, unless buy in is returned with win, like with some betting shops